# Cloudant to PouchDB replication

Tags: replication, cloudant, pouchdb

I am trying to setup replication between Cloudant and PouchDB.

I see that others have had issues. Are there any best practices to achieve this w/o a proxy?

Comment: Cloudant supports CORS (https://cloudant.com/blog/cors-and-faceted-search-coming-soon-to-a-cloudant-cluster-near-you) so you shouldn't need a proxy. You say "trying" - are you experiencing a particular problem? Replication between Cloudant and PouchDB works in general afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it should work out of the box. If it doesn't, the Cloudant folks are really helpful on the #cloudant freenode IRC channel.

If you suspect something is fundamentally wrong in the replication between PouchDB and Cloudant, you can sync from PouchDB to CouchDB and then from CouchDB to Cloudant. CouchDB is sort of the lingua franca.

Comment: Yes I had to enable CORS on cloudant. Works great now. Thanks!